# about arccos function in R: NaN produced

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `v2 = c(50,30,10,5)` and I would like to calculate the angle between `v2` and itself (i.e. the angle should be 0). I use the following codes:

```
norm_vec = function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))
```

Then I call

```
acos( as.numeric((v2 %*% v2) / (norm_vec(v2) * norm_vec(v2))) )
```

However, instead of getting 0, I got the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In acos(as.numeric((v2 %*% v2)/(norm_vec(v2) * norm_vec(v2)))) :
  NaNs produced
```

I checked the value of `as.numeric((v2 %*% v2) / (norm_vec(v2) * norm_vec(v2)))` as it is indeed a numeric of 1. I also checked `acos(1)` and the result is 0. What's wrong with my codes? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer: [acos(1) returns NaN for some values, not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026297/acos1-returns-nan-for-some-values-not-others)

And use pmin and pmax:
 `acos(pmin(pmax(as.numeric(v2 %*% v2) / (norm_vec(v2) * norm_vec(v2)),-1.0), 1.0))`

[1] 0

Answer (score 3):

If you set `x <- as.numeric((v2 %*% v2) / (norm_vec(v2) * norm_vec(v2)))`, you'll "see" that `x` is `1`. However, `x == 1` will return `FALSE`. And `x-1` will return a very tiny positive number: `2.220446e-16`. `acos` is not defined for numbers greater than 1.

The reason is that `sqrt(sum(x^2))` is slightly smaller than the true square root; the true square root is an irrational number (with infinitely many digits).  In this case, since you're multiplying `norm_vec(v2)` by itself anyways, why not just do:

```
acos( as.numeric(v2 %*% v2) / sum(v2^2) )
```

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestions! Sorry I have to only accept one solution... I appreciate your help :)